# home automation, android application raspberry reading/sending data

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on this project, i dont have a good experience in programming with android studio. I have tried to look in google or youtube for helps but no luck.

Where can I find some good tutorials to help me to understand what I need to do in my application to read data from the raspberry server( like reading temperature) or sending commandes to the server (like switch on/off led).

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at OpenHab. It is an open source project with quite a few tutorial and good community support.

http://docs.openhab.org/

Comment: Its not really helping, cant find anything related to raspberry( connect to raspberry server and read/send data.)